# Reference request: mod 2 cohomology of periodic KO theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy

The  mod  2 cohomology  of  the  connective ko spectrum  is  known  to  be   the  module $\mathcal{A}\otimes_{\mathcal{A}_2} \mathbb{F}_{2}$, where $\mathcal{A}$  denotes  the  Steenrod  algebra, and $\mathcal{A}_2$ denotes  the  subalgebra  generated  by  $Sq^1$  and $Sq^2$.

Where  can  I find  the   original  calculation for  referencing it ?
What  is  the  structure  as  module  over  the  steenrod  algebra  of  the  mod  2  cohomology of periodic  KO theory?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken $\pi_*(H\mathbb{F}_2\wedge KO)=0$ (it is a ring of positive characteristic containing an isomorphism between the additive and the multiplicative formal group law), so the answer to your second question is rather trivial

Comment: Indeed, as the periodicity generator ie the Bott element induces zero-map in ordinary homology!

Comment: It is more usual to use $\mathcal{A}_1$ to denote the algebra generated by $\mathrm{Sq}^1$ and $\mathrm{Sq}^2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ravenel in his *Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres* attributes this result to Stong, in [*Determination of $H^*(BO(k,⋯,∞),Z_2)$ and $H^∗(BU(k,⋯,∞),Z_2)$*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-107-03/S0002-9947-1963-0151963-5/S0002-9947-1963-0151963-5.pdf), but looking at that paper (which is concerned mainly with the "unstable" cohomology of the various constituent spaces of $ko$), he attributes this further to

> *Adams, J. F.*, On Chern characters and the structure of the unitary group, Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 57, 189-199 (1961). [ZBL0103.16001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0103.16001).

There you can find indeed the required result as Lemma 4.

Regarding your second question, the cohomology $H^*(KO;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is zero for chromatic reasons (the spectrum $KU\wedge H\mathbb{F}_2$ carries an isomorphism of the additive and multiplicative formal group law in characteristic two, so it must be trivial, and then you can use the fact that $KU=KO/\eta$ to conclude, since $\eta$ is nilpotent in $\pi_*KO$), hence the map $H^*(KO;\mathbb{F}_2)→H^*(ko;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is trivial.